# Replacing a plugin created textarea by WP editor

Tags: wordpress, textarea, wp-editor

Need your help guys. I have a page where by Private Content plugin I create a simple textarea field. What I need to do is to improve that textarea by adding rich text editor to it, I think standard WP one should be fine.

Can you please provide direct instruction which code I need to past and where exactly should I do that? Coding is not my strong suit as you can see. Trying google and searching here and there is some results but it is not clear enough for me to implement correctly.

Hope for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using the function

```
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array() );
```

you can display a default wordpress editor. Quick (unsanitized) example:

Your form content (don't forget to add `<form>` tags):

```
<?php wp_editor( 'I am a prefilled sample text', 'editorname' ?>
```

The script reading from that:

```
$editor_content = $_POST['editorname']
//do stuff, perhaps put to database
save_to_db( $editor_content ) //for example
```

A few quick things to note

- the editor is rendered aka directly echoed, so you don't have to add `echo`
- the `$editor_id` can **only** contain **lower cased letters**. no underscores.

but have a look yourself here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

wp_editor( $content, 'content_id', array('textarea_name' => 'content_id', 'editor_class'=>'requiredField', 'textarea_rows'=>'6', 'media_buttons' => true ,'tinymce' => true)  );

Comment: Replace text area html with above code and put  above that  this piece of code$content = get_post_meta($_GET['post'], 'post_meta _name', true);